# Javascript variable functions

Tags: javascript

I purchased a template for a website I'm trying to make help my friends with their dieting and modifying things to suit my needs.

I'm trying to edit a javascript function used to calculate a person's basal metabolic rate.

Part of code :

```
function calc_BMR() {
var a;
a = "kilo" == $("[name=weight_select]").val() ? parseFloat($("[name=Weight]").val()) : 6.23 * parseFloat($("[name=Weight]").val()) / 13.7;
var b = "cm" == $("[name=height_select]").val() ? parseFloat($("[name=Height]").val()) : 12.7 * parseFloat($("[name=Height]").val()) / 5, c = parseFloat($("[name=Age]").val());
if (0 >= b || 0 >= a || 0 >= c)
    return $("#indicator").text("Please complete the form!"), $("#bmr_value").text(""), -1;
a = $("input[name=Male]").prop("checked") ? 5 + 10 * a + 6.25 * b - 5 * c : 655 + 9.6 * a + 1.8 * b - 4.7 * c;
0 >= a ? ($("#bmr_value").text(""), $("#indicator").text("No kidding.Did you input the right value")) : ($("#bmr_value").text(a.toFixed(2)), $("#indicator").text("See your customized data below:"));
return a
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to understand the relationship in the formula between the male and female, I assumed that to the left of the colon is for male, and to the right is for female. But if I change the formula to match my formula it seems that what I change on the right hand side affects the value from the left side but not the other way around.

The left hand side of the formula gives me the correct result if I edit it, but the right hand side doesn't. I'm not sure how it works...

I am also trying to remove the option for metric or imperial units, I assume that something around the name=Weight parameters what allows for the option, but I'm not sure how to edit it so that it only uses one name=Weight value. The same goes for the Height value.

I have always been able to take a look at html, css and php and edit it too my liking by thinking through about how the code is written logically, but this has stumped me.

Sorry that I'm being lazy and not learning javascript from the ground up, I just need to get the job done quickly!

Comment: Those are ternary operators. Something like this: `n>50?console.log(">"):console.log("<");`

Comment: If you need to get the job done quickly, it would help to ask a specific question. This looks like vague rambling.

Comment: @melpomene To follow up, please get right to the question so it's concise

Comment: Sorry that the question is not specific. Would be too much to ask for someone to be able to explain how this code works in mathematical formulas / worded terms?

Comment: do you still need help or the below answer takes care of your query?

Comment: The below answer was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this code is littered with ternary operators, that seems to be what you are having the most trouble with.

Basic syntax:

```
condition ? a : b
```

is the same as

```
if (condition) {
  a
} else {
  b
}
```

For weight: If you want to use `kilo`, just remove that whole line and set `a` equal to `parseFloat($("[name=Weight]").val())`.

Same goes for height.

You are correct in assuming that changes to male are on the left side of the colon and changes to female are on the right. However you would have to post exactly what you are trying to change it to and your desired result if you expect any further assistance.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to remove the metric and adjust the formula getting the results I required. Thank you so much! I think I know what to look for when trying to understand the operators etc now too. Many thanks.